# Escape special characters of JSON in c#

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

I hava JSON object with one field has string value

```
" Ran a defrag removed a few virus' and tried again "
```

`'` is special character in JSON. I am using c#, NewtonSoftJSON library.

Is there any best way to  escape all special character with Newtonsoft and c#.

Comment: Escape for what use? `'` is not special in C#, so why do you need to escape it and to what?

Comment: Actually I want to escape special characters like "\".

Comment: And when you pass in a string through `NewtonSoftJSON` it doesn't do that already?

Comment: I am passing string -    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(parameters["ds"].ToString()).

Comment: Aaand? The result is?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(inputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me ->

System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(inputString).Substring(1, System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(inputString).Length - 2);